# When two different resources from two cookbooks have the same name, how can I specify which one to call?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a recipe that calls a custom resource called `sysctl_param`:

```
sysctl_param 'net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies' do
  value 1
end
```

However, as of Chef 14, `sysctl_param` is a built-in resource.  So when I tested my recipe against Chef 14, it used the Chef-built-in `sysctl_param` resource instead of my custom one.  This is breaking some of my tests because the built-in resource has slightly different behavior than the custom one.

How can I force Chef to use the custom `sysctl_param` resource instead of the built-in one?  Please assume that "rename the custom resource" is not an option - even if renaming is an option, I would strictly like to know the answer to the question "how can I choose which resource to run when there are resource naming conflicts?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a giant footgun, but it works (at least in Chef 12.x and 14.2; I haven't yet tested with other versions).

Chef has a "priority map" and a "handler map" that are used to resolve resource method names (e.g. `sysctl_param`) into resource class names (e.g. `Chef::Resource::Sysctl`).  You can use [these tools](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Platform/PriorityMap#priority-instance_method) to set which resource class responds to a given resource method.

For instance:

```
Chef.resource_priority_map.priority(:sysctl_param, [MyCookbook::SysctlParamResource])

sysctl_param 'net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies' do
  value 1
end
```

This will cause the custom resource (`MyCookbook::SysctlParamResource`) to be prioritized over the built-in resource.  You should be able to use the same approach regardless of the source of the resources: two cookbooks, one cookbook and one built-in, etc.

You can get the list of classes that can respond to a particular method with [`Chef.resource_handler_map.list(node, :my_resource_name)`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/NodeMap#list-instance_method).  You can verify how resources are resolved to classes by calling [`Chef::ResourceResolver.resolve(:my_resource_name)`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/ResourceResolver#resolve-instance_method).

Comment: I've edited your answer because they are _not_ public APIs. Not even in the same ballpark.

Comment: For people possibly finding this in the future, this API has changed in 14.3 and will potentially stop working.

Comment: @coderanger All of the methods I linked to are listed as public according to the API docs.  None of them were marked private.

Comment: We don't make consistent use of YARD markup in the Chef codebase (I think Chef actually slightly predates YARD's first public release even). This is why you don't see us linking to those docs anywhere. What you find through Google is not something we can control.

Comment: But YARD and the source code are the best documentation about what's public and what isn't, even if that wasn't the original intention. If there's no documentation (YARD, source code comments, or otherwise) about which classes/methods are public and which are private, and the classes/methods are technically useable (i.e. not marked with Ruby's `private` keyword), then effectively all of those classes/methods are public.

Comment: As a developer of Chef I am telling you point-blank that the YARD docs and source code are not considered documentation about what is and is not part of the public API. Only the official Chef docs do that. You can disagree with that, and we would certainly like to improve it, but you are incorrect here for the current state of the world.

Comment: Notably there are a lot of things that can't be formally `private` because they are used internally by other components, but are not part of our public API. That's actually the bulk of the code in Chef.

Comment: Pretty sure I wrote that API.  Please don't use it.  If you change your cookbook resource to declare `provides(:sysctl_param) { true }` that will cause the cookbook to win over the core resource and use at least a more public facing API than fiddling around with the priority map internals.

Comment: And yes, the docs are more definitive about what is a public api and what isn't, lots of Chef was written before YARD and before `@api private` so the absence of any comment in the source does not imply public.  We've been adding `@api private` as we go, but the source code is fairly massive and we don't have the resources for a full audit just to mark the public interfaces.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, there don't seem to be any official docs about what's considered public or private in the Chef API.  The only docs I can find are for the Chef Server API.  I don't see any for the client/cookbook aspect of things.  Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

We're in the process of improving this with the preview resources system in 14.3, but short version: you can't fix it, sorry. In 14.3 and onwards, new resources are being added in preview mode, which means the cookbook version will "win" until Chef 15.0.

Comment: The short version ("you can't") might still be the best tl;dr, but I did end up [finding a way to set which resource responds to a resource call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273617/1824868).